# Quantization aware training is too slow

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

I am trying to train a model with quantization aware training so that later i can convert it to quant.tflite for edge tpu accelerator. I used `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` as my pretrained model and downloaded the configuration file of `ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_coco`. When I remove this:

```
graph_rewriter { 
    quantization {
        delay: 48000
        weight_bits: 8
        activation_bits: 8
    }
}
```

from the configuration file the model takes 0.2 seconds for a step. With that quantization line it takes up to 1.1 second for a step.

Comment: Which documentation are you actually following, so we could get more context? Quantization aware training is expected to be slower since there are more internal ops needed by FakeQuantize.

Comment: I did not find a proper documentation for this, so what i am doing is using the configuration file of ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_coco because it has that quantization part. But it is almost 10x slower? is it fine or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It is really hard to tell without more context, but as far as I know, this is expected to be slower. I don't think you're doing anything wrong!

Comment: is there any difference between export_inference_graph.py and export_tflite_ssd_graph.py? i mean both return a frozen file but the one exported through export inference graph can not be converted to tflite (it can be but i don't know how).

Comment: if you are planning on converting the graph to tflite model, then you can use the export_tflite_ssd_graph, if you're just planning on using the .pb then export_inference_graph will suffice :)